# Content added by jquery is cleared after pressing submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/hvuSM/) is my code which I am currently working on. I have to display the value passed by the user. In here I am displaying only a string which I will modify afterwards. When I click the add button I get some strange code in my `alertbox`. This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvuSM/) which I have made while running fiddle I am getting shell form doesn't validate. May be my code have some problem. Here is the code which I get in my alertbox.

In the console I am getting a warning:

*The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.*

Please help me sorting this out.
Thanks

Dibya

**Follow up:** I have missed to mention. After clicking `Ok` button the text disappears in the div. What causes this? How can I prevent?

Comment: You can change `jQuery.nodeName( elem, 'option' )` to `$(elem).is('option')`

Comment: This is the error message I am getting when I click on the `add` button. I haven't written this code may be this is written in the jquery lib file which I have referred to.

Comment: Please have a look at my fiddle. The fiddle is my actual question.

Comment: Either use return false at the end of function or use button instead of submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
var x = $('input[name="time"]').val();
```

`$('input[name="time"]').val` refers to the `val` function and `alert(x)` in that case returns the string representation of `val`.

In order to call the method `val` and retrieve the returned value you need to use `val()`.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hvuSM/4/)

Comment: @Dibya updated, you need to return `false` other wise the form will get submitted.

Answer (score 1):

you mised the function call with **()** that's why you get displayed the jQuery function for val.

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvuSM/1/) is working because I added `()` to the `var x = $('input[name="time"]').val;` code.